# List of Lists in Dict weird initialization syntax

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to store lists in dicts, which works well, but i don't like the way i am constructing/initializing the lists. I would like to get rid of: ***dummy[i] = [(1,2,3)]***. Any Suggestions?

```
dummy = dict()

alphabet = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]

for i in alphabet:
    dummy[i] = [(1,2,3)] # <-- better initialization? 
    dummy[i].append([(1,2,3)])
```

The output is:

```
{'aaa': [(1, 2, 3), [(1, 2, 3)]], 'bbb': [(1, 2, 3), [(1, 2, 3)]], 'ccc': [(1, 2, 3), [(1, 2, 3)]]}
```

Sidequestion: Is there any other Data-type that supports multiple values for one key?

Comment: Could you please elaborate? As it stands now, it is hard to gauge what you are asking. For Example what do you mean by *I would like to get rid of: dummy[i] = [(1,2,3)]*

Comment: I dont like the way i am initializing the list in the dict. {i made an edit} is it clearer?

Comment: What are the values of the keys supposed to end up as? It doesn't look like your code is currently doing the right thing.

Comment: I printed the Output, its a dict, which collects lists of lists for every key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use what Ignacio suggests or use [dict.setdefault](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_setdefault.htm):

```
dummy = dict()

alphabet = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]

for i in alphabet:
    dummy.setdefault(i,[]).append((1,2,3)) # <-- better initialization?
```

If you wanted to initialise a dict with list values you could also create it with a dict comp:

```
alphabet = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
dummy = {k:[(1,2,3)] for k in alphabet}

print(dummy)
{'aaa': [(1, 2, 3)], 'bbb': [(1, 2, 3)], 'ccc': [(1, 2, 3)]}
```

If you have repeating keys setdefault and a defaultdict are what you want .

Comment: very cool,Is there anything i should consider when using this snippet?

Comment: @user1767754, a defaultdict is more efficient but sometimes when nesting `setdefault` actually fits better

Answer (score 1):

[`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) allows you to specify an initializer for non-existent keys.

```
import collections

dummy = collections.defaultdict(list)

alphabet = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]

for i in alphabet:
    dummy[i].append([(1,2,3)])
    dummy[i].append([(1,2,3)])
```

Comment: Great! Thats exactly what i was looking for. Is there anything i should consider when using collections.defaultdict()?

Comment: If your initializer returns the same mutable object each time it's called then each missing key will have the same value.